# Swift Массив ключ значение

Tags: массивы, swift, key

День добрый, подскажите плиз
я создал массив
`private var stackArray = [String: String]()`
добавляю в него данные
`self.stackArray[someKey] = someValue`
в итоге получился массив из пар ключ-значение

как удалить последнюю пару ? или предпоследнюю ?
есть функция например `removeValue(forKey: String)` - но она мне не подходит

Comment: У вас не массив а dictionary. Почему вам не подходит removeValue(forKey: String)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте, пожалуйста про массивы и словари https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Вы создаете не массив а словарь.

Массив - пронумерованный список

Словарь - список пар ключ-значение

В массиве можно извлечь значение по его позиции, напр.:

```
var array = ["1","2","3"]
print(array[0])
//1
array.remove(at: 0)
print(array[0])
//2
```

В словаре можно извлечь значение только по ключу:

```
var dict = [
"1":"One",
"2":"Two",
"3":"Three"
 ]

if let value = dict["1"]{
   print(value)
   //One
}

if let index = dict.index(forKey:"1"){
   dict.remove(at: index)
   print(dict)
   //["2":"Two","3":"Three"]
}
```